# How to move text in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text

How do I move text around in photoshop CS6, after I have already created a layer and placed the text in a project?

Comment: Please do not shout at us.

Answer (score 4):

When using the type tool i PS, it creates a text layer.

[image]

Select this. And use the `move tool` to move this layer around.

[image]

Comment: How to do it with keyboard shortcut while in edit text mode

Comment: I do this and the text won't move...it's not locked! Any ideas??